# SquareRootProcess in QuantLib - Python

Tags: stochastic-processes, python, quantlib

I would like to price an American put option using the SquareRootProcess class in QuantLib - Python but it seems that it does not exist. As the underlying follows the following model : 
$$\rm{d}S_t=rS_t\rm{d}t + \delta\sqrt{S_t}\rm{d}W_t, $$
setting $a = -r, b=0, \sigma=\delta$ in the SquareRootProcess class should be enough.
Is there any way I could price this option using QuantLib-Python ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

QuantLib does have the SquareRootProcess class ([link](https://www.quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_square_root_process.html)) but it has not been interfaced in SWIG and that's why it is not available in QuantLib-Python.

If you open an issue on github, maybe someone will pick it up.